# Pandas multi index dataframe to nested dictionary

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: {('A', 'a'): 1, ('A', 'b'): 6, ('B', 'a'): 2, ('B', 'b'): 7},
 1: {('A', 'a'): 2, ('A', 'b'): 7, ('B', 'a'): 3, ('B', 'b'): 8},
 2: {('A', 'a'): 3, ('A', 'b'): 8, ('B', 'a'): 4, ('B', 'b'): 9},
 3: {('A', 'a'): 4, ('A', 'b'): 9, ('B', 'a'): 5, ('B', 'b'): 1},
 4: {('A', 'a'): 5, ('A', 'b'): 1, ('B', 'a'): 6, ('B', 'b'): 2}})
```

which looks this:

```
     0  1  2  3  4
A a  1  2  3  4  5
  b  6  7  8  9  1
B a  2  3  4  5  6
  b  7  8  9  1  2
```

When I convert this to a dictionary via `to_dict` (regardless of stacking, unstacking), I get a dictionary whose keys are tuples:

```
df.transpose().to_dict()

{('A', 'a'): {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 ('A', 'b'): {0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 1},
 ('B', 'a'): {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6},
 ('B', 'b'): {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9, 3: 1, 4: 2}}
```

What I'd like instead is a nested dict like this:

```
{'A':{'a': {0: 1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5}, 'b':{0:6, 1:7, 2:8, 3:9,4:1}...
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to iterate through the outer levels (values 'A' and 'B') and use the `xs` method to slice the frame by those levels.

```
{level: df.xs(level).to_dict('index') for level in df.index.levels[0]}

{'A': {'a': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
  'b': {0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 1}},
 'B': {'a': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6},
  'b': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9, 3: 1, 4: 2}}}
```

Comment: Never knew about the xs method. Works great! thank you!

Comment: I tried this on my dataframe that had 3 levels of idexes. Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @NikhilVJ You can expand this approach to any number of levels. You just have to nest another dictionary comprehension around the previous one for each additional level. Here is an example for 2 levels:
`{level0: {level1: df.xs([level0, level1]).to_dict('index') for level1 in df.index.levels[1]} for level0 in df.index.levels[0]}`

Comment: Why `to_dict('index')` instead of just `to_dict()`?

Answer (score 3):

For n levels you could have something recursive like this:

```
def createDictFromPandas(df):
    if (df.index.nlevels==1):
        return df.to_dict()
    dict_f = {}
    for level in df.index.levels[0]:
        if (level in df.index):
            dict_f[level] = createDictFromPandas(df.xs([level]))
    return dict_f
```

Comment: Why is `if (level in df.index):` necessary? Surely if you're looping through `df.index.levels[0]` then that if statement will always be true?