# Aggregate Dataframe to Nested Dictionaries (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to convert this dataframe to dictionary,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: 44197,1: 44197,2: 44197,3: 44197,4: 44198,5: 44198,6: 44198,7: 44198,8: 44197,9: 44197,10: 44197,11: 44197,12: 44198,13: 44198,14: 44198,15: 44198},
 'Product': {0: 'B',1: 'A',2: 'C',3: 'D',4: 'B',5: 'A',6: 'C',7: 'D',8: 'B',9: 'A',10: 'C',11: 'D',12: 'B',13: 'A',14: 'C',15: 'D'},
 'Seller': {0: 'XXX',1: 'XXX',2: 'XXX',3: 'XXX',4: 'XXX',5: 'XXX',6: 'XXX',7: 'XXX',8: 'YYY',9: 'YYY',10: 'YYY',11: 'YYY',12: 'YYY',13: 'YYY',14: 'YYY',15: 'YYY'},
 'Price': {0: 10,1: 25,2: 36,3: 14,4: 60,5: 31,6: 2,7: 7,8: 5,9: 9,10: 10,11: 26,12: 36,13: 78,14: 95,15: 100}})
```

Here is the dataframe look like,

[image]

I want to create dict key based on Seller then for every date groupe products as key so A is key and Price is item

Order is Seller => Date (as the will be 1000 dates) => for each date you will have 4 products and thier corrsponding prices.

Does anyone know how to do this ? My true table is very large 100K lines, my goal is to make this as much fast as possible also.

My results I want to have will look like this:

`{XXX:{"01/01/2021":{ A : Value1 , B : Value2 , C : Value3 , D : Value4 },"02/01/2021":{ .......}}, "YYY" : ....... }`

Comment: What's the example desired output??

Comment: {XXX:{"01/01/2021":{ A : Value1 , B : Value2 , C : Value3 , D : Value4 },"02/01/2021": .......}, "YYY" : ....... } @U12-Forward loooks like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Pandas DataFrame to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Craicerjack read my post before send corrections.

Comment: Please share data in excel; in the form of link

Comment: @Mohith7548 I did add the Data to the post !

Comment: Note to mods/close voters: this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary). This question is a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

First, set your desired nested index to a multi index using set_index:

```
>>> df.set_index(["Seller", "Date", "Product"])
                      Price
Seller Date  Product
XXX    44197 B           10
             A           25
             C           36
             D           14
       44198 B           60
             A           31
             C            2
             D            7
YYY    44197 B            5
             A            9
             C           10
             D           26
       44198 B           36
             A           78
             C           95
             D          100
```

Then convert the multi-index to nested dictionaries using the to_dict method. Each column is a key in the dict, and multi-index are converted to keys, each of which is a tuple:

```
>>> df_transformed = df.set_index(["Seller", "Date", "Product"]).to_dict()
>>> df_transformed
{'Price': {('XXX', 44197, 'B'): 10, ('XXX', 44197, 'A'): 25, ('XXX', 44197, 'C'): 36, ('XXX', 44197, 'D'): 14, ('XXX', 44198, 'B'): 60, ('XXX', 44198, 'A'): 31, ('XXX', 44198, 'C'): 2, ('XXX', 44198, 'D'): 7, ('YYY', 44197, 'B'): 5, ('YYY', 44197, 'A'): 9, ('YYY', 44197, 'C'): 10, ('YYY', 44197, 'D'): 26, ('YYY', 44198, 'B'): 36, ('YYY', 44198, 'A'): 78, ('YYY', 44198, 'C'): 95, ('YYY', 44198, 'D'): 100}}
```

...capture the Price column by itself (but in this case it is of course the only column):

```
>>> price_dict = df_transformed.to_dict()["Price"]
>>> price_dict
{('XXX', 44197, 'B'): 10, ('XXX', 44197, 'A'): 25, ('XXX', 44197, 'C'): 36, ('XXX', 44197, 'D'): 14, ('XXX', 44198, 'B'): 60, ('XXX', 44198, 'A'): 31, ('XXX', 44198, 'C'): 2, ('XXX', 44198, 'D'): 7, ('YYY', 44197, 'B'): 5, ('YYY', 44197, 'A'): 9, ('YYY', 44197, 'C'): 10, ('YYY', 44197, 'D'): 26, ('YYY', 44198, 'B'): 36, ('YYY', 44198, 'A'): 78, ('YYY', 44198, 'C'): 95, ('YYY', 44198, 'D'): 100}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932755/arbitrarily-nested-dictionary-from-tuples/50932879#50932879) from Martijn Pieters for help with turning the tuple keys into nested dictionaries. I will just regurgitate that below for convenience, but it really is Pieters' solution:

```
def nest(d: dict) -> dict:
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        target = result
        for k in key[:-1]:  # traverse all keys but the last
            target = target.setdefault(k, {})
        target[key[-1]] = value
    return result
```

Finally:

```
>>> nest(price_dict)
{'XXX': {44197: {'B': 10, 'A': 25, 'C': 36, 'D': 14}, 44198: {'B': 60, 'A': 31, 'C': 2, 'D': 7}}, 'YYY': {44197: {'B': 5, 'A': 9, 'C': 10, 'D': 26}, 44198: {'B': 36, 'A': 78, 'C': 95, 'D': 100}}}
```

The OP mentions in a comment that the order of the dates matters. It is important to note that the order of the multi-index of the `df_transformed` will determine the order of the final nested dictionary. If you want to sort it in different ways before turning it into the dictionary, use [.sort_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

Comment: The groupby is correct thats what I'm trying to reach in dict ....

Comment: @heuveny yes although it's actually not really a groupby, it's a change to the index to match the nesting of the dict keys you want.

Comment: @heuveny I finally finished my answer. Sorry it took a while!

Answer (score 1):

```py
groupped_df = df.groupby(['Seller', 'Date']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Product').to_dict()).apply(lambda x: x['Price'])
desired_dict = {level: groupped_df.xs(level).to_dict() for level in groupped_df.index.levels[0]}
```

output:

```
Out[100]: 
{'XXX': {44197: {'B': 10, 'A': 25, 'C': 36, 'D': 14},
  44198: {'B': 60, 'A': 31, 'C': 2, 'D': 7}},
 'YYY': {44197: {'B': 5, 'A': 9, 'C': 10, 'D': 26},
  44198: {'B': 36, 'A': 78, 'C': 95, 'D': 100}}}
```

On the first line we are grouping and creating a series where seller and date are indices and values is a dictionary as desired (the most nested one). This is what happens on `groupped_df = df.groupby(['Seller', 'Date']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Product').to_dict())`, but since it creates some extra "data" inside the dictionary, I also added `.apply(lambda x: x['Price'])` to select only the price.

After the first line the `groupped_df` looks like this:

```py
Out[101]: 
Seller  Date 
XXX     44197     {'B': 10, 'A': 25, 'C': 36, 'D': 14}
        44198       {'B': 60, 'A': 31, 'C': 2, 'D': 7}
YYY     44197       {'B': 5, 'A': 9, 'C': 10, 'D': 26}
        44198    {'B': 36, 'A': 78, 'C': 95, 'D': 100}
```

The second line shift the multi index into a nested dictionary, like in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150769/pandas-multi-index-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary) (notice no need to 'index' arg in `to_dict`)

Comment: This is perfect, do you have an idea how to order the dates key from old to new ?

Comment: they are dictionary keys, they don't have order. Dictionary doesn't contain any order between it's keys

Comment: @Roim great answer! but fyi python dictionaries have been ordered since i think 3.7.

Comment: @RicksupportsMonica didn't know that. thank you. @heunevy my bad. I assume there's should be `.sort_index` inside the nested loop, but I'll check it later on and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Reshape the dataframe with `pivot` then create temporary column and assign the records, finally `unstack` on `level=0` and use `to_dict` to create a dictionary

```
s = df.pivot(['Seller', 'Date'], 'Product', 'Price')
s.assign(r=s.to_dict('records'))['r'].unstack(0).to_dict()
```

---

```
{'XXX': {44197: {'A': 25, 'B': 10, 'C': 36, 'D': 14},
         44198: {'A': 31, 'B': 60, 'C': 2, 'D': 7}},
 'YYY': {44197: {'A': 9, 'B': 5, 'C': 10, 'D': 26},
         44198: {'A': 78, 'B': 36, 'C': 95, 'D': 100}}}
```